# Rhythmbox "cannot resolve proxy hostname" error

Tags: 12.04, rhythmbox

I keep getting cannot resolve proxy hostname. Have no idea what this means can't find directions for ubuntu 12.04 and rhythmbox to correct. I need simple step by step instructions

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. But since I use some vpn connections I addition with proxies I found an empty setting in my system proxy setting in Ubuntu 
under System Settings -> Network -> Network Proxy 
there was no url for the server, port set to some number and method set to manual. I set to method none, applied the settings and I was good to go.

sincerely tingel2k